# Multiplying each object properties by 2 and creating new object from the result

Tags: javascript

Is this a good practice multiplying each object properties by 2 without mutating original object or there's easy way of achieving same result?

```
let salaires = {
    'john': [20, 8, 5, 90, 22],
    'pete': [50, 5, 400, 3],
    'seun': 40
}

let x = []
let newArr = []
let salaryNew = {}

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(salaires)) {
    newArr.push([key, value])
}

for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    let x = newArr[i].flat(10)
    console.log(x)
    let s = x.slice(0, 1)
    let see = x.map(function (i) {
        return i * 2
    })
    let finalResult = s.concat(see.slice(1))
    salaryNew[`${finalResult[0]}`] = see.slice(1)
    console.log(salaryNew)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the properties of the new object using bracket notation and map the array.

```js
let salaires = {
    'john': [20, 8, 5, 90, 22],
    'pete': [50, 5, 400, 3],
    'seun': 40
  },
  salaryNew = {}

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(salaires)) {
  salaryNew[key] = Array.isArray(value) ? value.map(n => 2 * n) : 2 * value;
}

console.log(salaryNew);
```

Notice, that multitype data increases complexity, it's recommended to use a single type only, you could wrap the single value into an array as well.

Answer (score -1):

Take all the keys from the object with `Object.keys`, then call `reduce` over them and multiply each property value depending on if it's an array or a number

```
const K = 2;
const result = Object.keys(salaries).reduce((acc, name) => {
  const salary = salaries[name];
  if (salary instanceof Array) {
    acc[name] = salary.map(item => item * K);
  } else {
    acc[name] = salary * K;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
```